# Which actors from the original Star Trek pilot "The Cage" appeared in later Star Trek media?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

This is an intensive one.

From the original pilot "The Cage" with Jeffery Hunter as the captain, which actors have been later credited in **any** Star Trek media?  This includes series, film, audio, comics (like as a writer), et cetera.

Please site names and details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excluding 'The Menagerie: Parts I & II' (which includes *archival footage* of 'The Cage') a number of actors appeared in both the pilot episode and *other episodes* of Star Trek.

- **[Leonard Nimoy](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000559/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t3)** continued to play Mr. Spock in TOS, TNG and the subsequent films.
- **[Majel Barrett](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000854/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t4)** played a host of characters in TOS, TNG, DS9 and Voyager including the voice of the computer, Nurse Chapel and Lwaxana Troi.
- [**Tom Curtis**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0193528/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t8) appeared as Corrigan in 'The Cage' and as an uncredited extra in 'Court Martial'.
- [**Sandra Lee Gimpel**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0319831/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10) appeared as a Talosian in 'The Cage' and as the M-113 monster in 'The Man Trap'.
- **[Bob Johnson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0424614/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t13)** appeared in three more Trek episodes as a voice actor in  'Assignment: Earth', 'The Immunity Syndrome' and 'The Gamesters of Triskelion'.
- **[John Lormer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0521070/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t14)** appeared in two additional episodes; 'For the World Is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky' and 'The Return of the Archons' as Tamar.
- **[Ed Madden](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0534579/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t15)** appeared in 'The Cage' as a Federation Geologist and 'The Enemy Within' as Fisher.
- **[Janos Prohaska](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0698512/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t19)** appeared in three additional TOS episodes; 'The Savage Curtain', 'A Private Little War' and 'The Devil in the Dark' as the Horta.
- **[Malachi Throne](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0861943/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t25)** was in 'The Cage' as a voice actor and in TNG episodes 'Unification, Part I' and 'Unification, Part II' as Romulan Senator Pardek.
- **[Frank da Vinci](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0196326/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr39)** appeared in ***78*** episodes of Star Trek TOS as Lt. Brent and a veritable [host of other uncredited roles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142683/20774).

Comment: This is a much more complete answer than the accepted one. At least I can upvote it. Oddly, though, it mentions Majel Barrett as Lwaxana Troi but not Nurse Chapel.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - What can I say? I'm a child of the TNG generation.

Comment: @Valorum-You forgot mention of Eddie Paskey

Comment: @sfhq_sf - Was he in "The Cage"?

Comment: The character Mendez wasn't in 'The Cage' - that was 'The Menagerie'

Comment: @Valorum-IMDB has his first appearance as uncredited in  "The Man Trap" and also uncredited in "The Menagerie", I think that's as close to "The Cage" as you're going to get.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - Hmm. Not close enough. The OP wanted to know about people who were in the pilot and later shows.

Comment: @NKCampbell - You are, of course, correct. Edited.

Answer (score 10):

Partial list only of other movie/tv credits, from [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Cage_%28episode%29):

- Leonard Nimoy as Spock
- Majel Barrett-Roddenberry as Number One (and later Nurse Chapel, Lwaxana Troi as well as the computer voice in TNG, DS9 and VOY)
- [Malachi Throne](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Malachi_Throne) as the voice of the Talosian Keeper, later was in the Menagerie and in TNG as a Romulan.

Comment: The episode article at Memory Alpha has links to several of the actors, many of which have expanded lists of Trek relations.

Comment: Jeffrey Hunter appears in The Menagerie: Part I & II, but it's archive footage, not new content.