# Which actor has portrayed the most distinct roles in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, actors

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31779/1639) got me to thinking about how there have been *many* actors who have had several roles across the Star Trek franchise. It seems that once an actor demonstrates good performance in that franchise, it is *very likely* (at least more so than in other franchises, or it might just be my imagination) that they will be seen as another minor or major character later on.

So, I'm now curious to know which actor has had the most distinct roles in the franchise. Some likely candidates have already been named in the linked thread (e.g.: Majel Barrett, Jeffrey Combs) but I'd like to know if these are really *the* top ones?

Note that this question is asking about *distinct* roles. That is, variations of the same character (e.g.: holographic or dream-state representations, shapeshifters or alien possessions, etc.) do not count. I'd also like to exclude *very closely* related characters (e.g.: ancestors, descendants, similarly-crafted androids, etc. - I was originally going to include these, but then realized that [Brent Spiner](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Brent_Spiner#Additional_characters) *might* be an all-too-easy winner).

Also, to keep this question in an SE-sized scope, I'm only looking to draw from primary-universe live-action productions up to and including ENT.  That includes:

- TOS, and related films
- TNG, and related films
- DS9
- VOY
- ENT

This excludes:

- J.J. Abrams' Star Trek universe
- TAS
- Books
- Comics
- Video Games
- Fanfic

Related: [Which character in Star Trek has been played by the most actors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105832)

Comment: If you limit it to the original series (a different question than you're asking), [Janos Prohaska](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Janos_Prohaska) may hold the record, with 5 roles of 5 different species. He's probably most famous for playing the Cookie Bear on the Andy Williams show.

Comment: For the actresses, don't forget [Susie Plakson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0686442/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), who played Q's wife, Worf's wife, an Andorian, and some others. Also, Data played a lot of holograms in "A Fistful of Datas", but what about the whole crew in the episode where Worf quantum leaped from one ship to another? Wouldn't that beat Data's record?

Comment: What about Clint Howard who appeared in TOS, Deep Space Nine, and Enterprise

Comment: @Iszi:   Are stunt performers allowed??

Comment: I find the criteria to specifically exclude Brent Spiner a little disappointing. We don't actually know if he would have more distinct characters compared to, say, a recurring extra.

Comment: @Ellesedil:    Ask a different question then.   (I have a good answer.)

Comment: Brent Spiner always plays Dr. Soong's face (except in *Enterprise*) because Data, Lore, and B4 are all designed to look like him.

Comment: It only took me three years, but I've finally managed to find someone to top 11.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

While trying to add to Kyle's answer, I came across Randy Oglesby's entry on IMDB. The trivia blurb at the top of his page actually gives the answer: there are four actors who are tied for *seven* Trek roles each:

1. J.G. Hertzler ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0381117/)) ([Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/J.G._Hertzler))

   - [Martok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Martok) (and several variations thereof) - DS9
   - [Vulcan Captain & Prophet](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Saratoga_(NCC-31911)_personnel) - DS9
   - [Roy Ritterhouse](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Roy_Ritterhouse) - DS9
   - [Laas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Laas) - DS9
   - [Holosuite Guest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bashir_62_holograms#Guest_.234) - DS9
   - [Hirogen Fighter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Hirogen#Hirogen_Tsunkatse_Fighter) - VOY
   - [Kolos](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kolos_(Klingon)) - ENT
   - [Klingon Commander](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Klingons_(22nd_century)#Klingon_Commander) - ENT
   - Though out-of-scope for this question, IMDB says J.G. Hertzler did portray a "record-breaking eighth unique character" in the fan film, [*Of Gods and Men*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0835378/).
2. Randy Oglesby ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0644750/)) ([Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Randy_Oglesby))

   - [Scholar/Artist](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Riva%27s_chorus) - TNG
   - [Ah-Kel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ah-Kel) - DS9
   - [Ro-Kel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ro-Kel) - DS9
   - [Silarin Prin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Silaran_Prin) - DS9
   - [Kir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kir_(Brenari)) - VOY
   - [Trena'L](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trena%27L) - ENT
   - [Degra](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Degra) - ENT
3. Jeffrey Combs ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001062/)) ([Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Combs))

   - [Brunt](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brunt) (and mirror version) - DS9
   - [Weyoun](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Weyoun) (all incarnations and variations) - DS9
   - [Tiron](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tiron) - DS9
   - [Kevin Mulkahey](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Mulkahey) - DS9
   - [Holosuite Guest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bashir_62_holograms#Farewell_Party_Guests) - DS9
   - [Penk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Penk) - VOY
   - [Krem](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Krem) - ENT
   - [Thy'lek Shran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thy%27lek_Shran) (and holographic version) - ENT
4. Thomas Kopache ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0465664/)) ([Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Kopache))

   - [Mirok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirok) - TNG
   - [Train Engineer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Orient_Express_holograms#The_Engineer) - TNG
   - [Enterprise-B Communications Officer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-B)_personnel#Communications_officer) - Generations
   - [Viorsa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Viorsa) - VOY
   - [Kira Taban](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kira_Taban) - DS9
   - [Tos](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tos) - ENT
   - [Sphere Builder test subject](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Sphere_Builders#Sphere_Builder_Test_Subject) - ENT

*Editor's Note: It seems IMDB does not count the appearances of Hertzler & Combs as "Holosuite Guests" from the DS9 episode [What You Leave Behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode)) in their tally.  When we add these in, it leaves Hertzler & Combs alone as being tied with 8 appearances each.*

Comment: @Iszi The links are awesome! Love seeing the pictures of the characters. Great question.

Comment: @MattP Nice work.

Comment: @Iszi:   MattPeterson's answer seems to indicate this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: There are 8 links for Hertzler, with another one added. Shouldn't that be 9 roles, making him second behind @KyleJones answer?

Comment: @ThePopMachine -- I agree. The answer below (Vaughn Armstrong) should be the accepted answer, but I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: @Iszi needs to do it.

Comment: @Iszi does appear occasionally.   Maybe he/she will notice eventually

Comment: Jeffrey Combs played such varied roles - Shran, Brunt, and Weyoun are so unbelievably different from each other.

Comment: Not sure the DS9 “Far Beyond the Stars” characters count. Aren’t those “dream variations” of their primary characters?

Comment: +1 for Jeffrey Combs with the latest Lower Decks episode.

Answer (score 62):

According to one of the special features in the *Star Trek: Voyager* disc set, [Vaughn Armstrong](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0035932/) has played 11 (!) unique Star Trek characters.  He's been on all the live-action Trek series except the original.  Looking at iMDb I found:

On Enterprise:

- [Maxwell Forrest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maxwell_Forrest)
- [Kreetassan Captain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Kreetassans#Kreetassan_Captain)
- [Klingon Captain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/IKS_Somraw_personnel#Captain)

On Voyager:

- [Telek R'Mor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Telek_R%27Mor)
- [Lansor / Two of Nine](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lansor)
- [Vidiian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vidiian) Captain (in ["Fury"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fury_(episode)))
- [Alpha-Hirogen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Hirogen#Hirogen_Alpha_2_.282377.29)
- [Korath](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Korath)

On Deep Space Nine:

- [Gul Danar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Danar)
- [Seskal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Seskal)

On Next Generation:

- [Captain Korris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Korris)

Comment: Wow, he would certainly beat all four of the actors in the current top answer. I checked his characters, and they all seem legit (i.e. credited).

Comment: You forgot Captain Maximilian Forrest of the ISS Enterprise in the mirror universe. I think that would qualify as a separate and distinct character from Admiral Forrest.

Answer (score 26):

[Frank da Vinci](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0196326/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr39) has portrayed no less than **12** separate and distinct roles in Star Trek TOS.

- Lt. Brent
- Transporter Operator
- Crewman
- Security Guard
- Soldier at Party
- Capellan Warrior
- Vulcan Aide
- Vulcan Ceremonial Aide
- Lt. Osborne
- Vinci
- Eminiar Guard
- Security Guard Brent

Additionally he's acted as a body-double and stand-in on 78 other occasions.

Comment: This should *seriously* be the winning answer.

Comment: @Lexible - Since OP is nowhere to be seen, I shall have to settle for the quiet knowledge that my answer is the best one.

Answer (score 10):

According to iMDB and my own heavy viewing of Star Trek franchise TV shows, Jeffrey Combs and J. G. Hertzler share the crown with six roles each.

Combs played Weyoun, Tiron, Brunt, Officer Mulkahey, and a patron in Vic's Lounge on *Deep Space Nine*.  He also played Commander Shran on *Enterprise*.

Hertzler played Martok, Roy Rittenhouse, Laas, and a patron in Vic's Lounge on *Deep Space Nine*.  He also played a nameless Klingon captain and Advocate Kolos on *Enterprise*.

Comment: Hertzler also played a Vulcan captain in the DS9 pilot "Emissary" under a slightly different name (John Noah Hertzler).

Comment: For Combs, you missed [Penk from VOY](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Penk), and [Krem from ENT](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Krem). Strictly speaking, Officer Mulkahey might be filed under "variations of a primary character" as most other characters in his episode were. EDIT: Looks like [IMDB Disagrees](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001062/bio) - Mulkahey *is* counted as a separate character.

Answer (score 5):

William Shatner played James T. Kirk, 'good' Kirk, 'bad' Kirk, Mirror universe Kirk, Sam Kirk, Lord Garth, Janice Lester, Martia, and Sargon.

Comment: Could you add references for some of these? Also, is this more than the others?

Comment: Source for Sam Kirk can be found on Memory Alpha https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/George_Samuel_Kirk ; and all others are immediately obvious from their episodes: "The Enemy Within", "Mirror, Mirror", "Whom Gods Destroy", "Return To Tomorrow", "Turnabout Intruder".

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer says there are seven.

This answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103106/3823 indicates the Patricia Tallman appears in **eight** roles.

(There are seven images near the bottom of the answer, plus the role of Dr. Crusher in the question at the top.)

Comment: Praxis's answer also indicates she body doubled for Kira and Jadzia. So... that's 10?

Answer (score 4):

Majel Barrett :

- First Officer under Captain Pike (TOS Pilot)
- Nurse Chapel -ST TOS;
- Various -ST TAS
- L. Troy/voice of computer-ST TNG
- L.Troy/voice of computer-ST DS9
- Voice of computer-ST VOY
- voice of computer-ST ENT

So the whole lot really...

Answer (score 0):

Barbara Babcock played 6 separate roles in classic Trek. Per IMDB:

- The Lights of Zetar (1969) ... Zetar (voice)
- Plato's Stepchildren (1968) ... Philana
- The Tholian Web (1968) ... Cmdr. Loskene (voice, uncredited)
- Assignment: Earth (1968) ... Beta 5 Computer / Isis (voice, uncredited)
- A Taste of Armageddon (1967) ... Mea 3
- The Squire of Gothos (1967) ... Trelane's Mother (voice, uncredited)

Comment: The question is who played the most roles, and there have been actors who played 7.