# Is this Patricia Tallman in the TNG episode "Half a life"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actor-identification

Sorry for troubling you guys, but I just *have* to know.. could this be Patricia Tallman in the elevator in ST TNG episode "Half a Life", time index 08:19? That's season 4. Was she already working there then?

[image: STTNG ep Half a Life - is this Patricia Tallman]

Comment: Based on the answers to [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103448/which-actor-appears-as-the-most-different-species-in-star-trek) question, I would speculate not.

Comment: It doesn't look like her.

Comment: Hmm, I think it looks quite a bit like her, and she's got the figure.

Comment: It is not listed in her IMDB article

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [Cameron Oppenheimer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cameron) playing Tactical Officer [Ensign Kellogg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kellogg). The actress actually 'stood in' for Gates McFadden on several occasions (as did Patricia Tallman due to their similar physique) which I'm assuming is why you're mistaking the two of them.

[image]

As far as I can tell, her only line (despite appearing in over a dozen episodes) was "*Counselor?*" in TNG: Eye of the Beholder

Comment: Wow... ask and ye shall know. Thanks a million!

Comment: @PkP - "*The best way to find yourself is to lose yourself in the service of others"*