# Is this Marina Sirtis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, character-identification

[image]

(+1s should be given for least wordy question on site)

Comment: -1s should be given for least interesting question on site, @TheDoc'sproxy :-)

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103104/is-this-beverly-crusher

Comment: Also, you should include a description of the season/episode and possibly even scene this is found in. Otherwise this is literally just a picture and a title, and not at all searchable.

Comment: "Is this Deanna Troi?" and "Is this Marina Sirtis?" are very different questions! I vote to undo the edits and restore the original question -- especially since the existing (good) answer sounds a bit silly after the edits to the title.

Comment: Is this Sirtis? Is it? Tisn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No it's not!

This is actually [Nora Leonhardt](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nora_Leonhardt) who was the stand-in for Marina Sirtis who played Troi.

Here's a picture of Leonhardt:

[image]

and now compared with Sirtis:

[image]

In fact, she's not actually playing Troi in the above image; it's some junior science officer who holds the rank of ensign.  If you look closely at the above picture, you'll see that that character isn't actually Deanna Troi at all - she has only got the rank of ensign; but we know that

> By 2364, Troi held the rank of lieutenant commander. That year, she
>   was assigned as ship's counselor aboard the USS Enterprise-D. (TNG:
>   "Encounter at Farpoint")

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deanna_Troi))

Comment: OMG! Thanks for the quick response! This makes total sense.

Comment: @CandiedMango Shameless!