# Did any Star Trek actor play both a Starfleet crewmember and one of the encountered aliens?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, uss-enterprise, actors

Is there any actor who has played, in different *Star Trek* episodes, both a **Starfleet crewmember (of the Enterprise, Voyager, etc.)** and one of the **alien strangers encountered by the crew**?

---

Clarifications:

- All series (TOS, TNG, DS9, etc.), plus the stand-alone films, are included in the scope of this question. (I'd be most interested in an actor who's appeared in both these roles in the same series, but also in whether anyone's been e.g. a crewmember in TOS and an alien in TNG.)
- Neither of the roles in question needs to be a recurring role; either or both could be a one-off appearance.
- The crewmember role needs to be that of one of the primary vessels (the Enterprise, the DS9 space station, etc.)

Comment: Almost every member of the cast of DS9 (as well as Captain Picard) played a wormhole alien at some point.  This might be outside the spirit of the question though.

Comment: Having seen a few of the answers, I'd now like to specify that the crewmember must be human. But it'd be bad form to make an edit that invalidates existing answers, so I think I'll have to leave it...

Comment: I was thinking about pretty much everyone in DS9's "Far Beyond the Stars", but unfortunately that doesn't fit the "alien strangers encountered by the crew" condition. We see the regular crew as humans, not aliens, and I think even the "encountered by the crew" part would be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @randal'thor : ThePopMachine makes a point.  This question is technically a subset of other similar questions, and some of the answers here (including the highest-rated one) are answers to previous questions (and one litmus test for "dupe" is whether another question has the same answer)...

Comment: [Here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103448/which-actor-appears-as-the-most-different-species-in-star-trek) would be one of the related questions to which I referred

Comment: @randal'thor : I assume you saw the comments above?  Would you feel it were unjust if this were closed as a dupe?  At this point, it really should be.  (Note: your rep earned and the rep of the answerers would be unaffected.  The only effect is that no new answers can be posted, which at this point is a good thing.  As The PopMachine pointed out, people are poaching answers from the other questions, including wording and images, to answer this one.)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : See above. ^

Comment: @Praxis Well, this question isn't asking the same as the other questions; it's just that a few particular actors are examples of the type called for in both questions. Arguably, since this question asks "Did any...", it was already solved by the time the first answer came in, but it would've been silly to close it then! And there's not much incentive for anyone to post new answers now, as they'd languish at the bottom without upvotes. Protecting the question would probably be a good move though. And I won't be offended if you VTC - do what you think best :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : Thanks.  I wanted your thoughts before I did anything.  I'm happy just to protect it for now (which I've done).  If ThePopMachine still feels strongly about closing, he can start a vote.  But as for myself, I'll leave it be for now --- as you say, there's not much incentive at this point to post new answers.

Comment: @Praxis, randalthor:   Don't worry, I have taken the same position before that a question is not a duplicate, but the policy is that questions which *have an answer* already in a different question are duplicates.   There is nothing Wrong with being marked duplicate.   To be frank, a question with 17 answers should have had some attention sooner and there would be a good argument for VTC as 'too broad' or 'lacks research effort'.   So I think duplicate is the least that should be done.    I hope this doesn't seem harsh -- don't forget -- I earned more rep on this question than you.

Comment: ...  Furthermore people who get their answers from other questions should at the very least be linking to the source to give credit.   In addition, there is no reason for anyone to post more answers do a 'did this ever occur' question after it has already been answered.   17 answers is just preposterous.      So I hope that this will also encourage the right behavior in the future.   Or at least nudge answerers a little in the right direction.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## [Tim Russ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Russ)

played the Vulcan security officer on Voyager and also a Klingon named T'Kar on *DS9*

[image]
[image]

He also played a *human* crewmember on the Enterprise-B, which fulfills OP's comment that he wished it was human, but he wasn't going to change the question.

[image]

Comment: Added this in case you think Worf and Worf's grandfather of the same species played by the same actor is a loophole

Comment: He also played a (seemingly) human in `Starship Mine` S06E18

Comment: He also played a (different) human crew member on the Enterprise-B during `Star Trek: Generations`

Comment: @Derek, yes,  I know,  but not alien.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I also remember Picard beating him up when he's a terrorist or something, I want to say they ran away from a Barium scan...and I just now remembered that I'm pretty sure the episode was called "starship mine"...or something close to that

Comment: @VapedCrusader, uh Derek already said that.   And a barium scan is something totally different than a baryon  sweep.   <chuckle>

Answer (score 59):

## Patricia Tallman

Played the following enterprise/starfleet crewmembers:

[image: Enterprise-D Officer, TNG: "Power Play"] [image: Enterprise-D Officer, Generations] [image: Define weapons officer, DS9: "The Way of the Warrior"]

In order she is portraying:

- Enterprise-D Officer, TNG episode "Power Play"
- Enterprise-D Officer, Star Trek: Generations
- Defiant Weapons Officer, DS9 episode, "The Way of the Warrior"

She also played the following aliens:

[image: Starship Mine] [image: Nima, DS9: "Battle Lines"] [image: Alien impersonating a romulan, TNG: "Timescape"] [image: Taresian, VOY: "Favorite Son"]

In order these are:

- Kiros, TNG: "Starship Mine"
- Nima, DS9: "Battle Lines"
- Alien (impersonating a Romulan), TNG: "Timescape"
- Taresian, VOY: "Favorite Son"

Comment: Why the downvote?  Have I done something wrong with this answer?

Comment: Don't let it get you down.   It just happens.   I can't speak for the downvoter, but I personally believe that if we don't interpret the question to mean a main castmember, then the question essentially is covered by [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31810/which-actor-has-portrayed-the-most-distinct-roles-in-the-star-trek-universe).   Hence not as interesting an answer as Tim Russ.  But that's just me.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ok.  I thought I'd done something wrong. Also,   the question specifically states "starfleet crewmember" rather than "bridge officer" or "regular" or something else.  One of the Tallman roles is weapons officer on the defiant, which is certainly not a regular, but is more than an extra seen in the background.

Comment: I agree,  this is a valid answer pending any clarification.   Downvotes are a normal part of life, especially on a question with lots of answers.   I hope you'll have fun participating here!  Welcome to SFF.SE!

Comment: @ThePopMachine Thanks.  I sort of took my lead from the OP who posted an answer to his own question which included someone who made a single appearance as an enterprise crewmember.

Comment: In case anyone is thinking "she looks familiar", she was Lyta Alexander on B5.

Comment: @RobChurch Thanks, I was thinking precisely that

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken she also played Dr Crusher?

Comment: @Liath.  Nope, that was Gates McFadden.  Patricia Tallman is a well-known stuntwoman.  Anytime you need a moderately tall, slim woman to take a fall or take a hit, they usually get her.  She was Laura Dern's stunt double in Jurassic Park, among others.  And yes, I loved her role as Lyta Alexander on B5.

Comment: Tallman was one of the major actors of Star Trek TNG who never got as much name recognition. Mostly as Crusher's stunt double, she got a lot of screen time for a non-main castmember.

Comment: @Meower68 not primary but as a Stunt Double http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103104/is-this-beverly-crusher/103106#103106

Answer (score 26):

## Michelle Forbes

Played Ro Laren of the Enterprise (8 appearances in Seasons 5-7):

[image: Ro Laren]

And played Dara, an alien from Kaelon II, daughter Doctor Timicin in the TNG Episode, "Half a Life."

[image: Dara]

Both of these roles are in the same series, TNG.

Comment: Great answer.  :-)

Answer (score 24):

## Michael Dorn

The actor played Lt./Cmdr. Worf and [Col. Worf](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf_%28Colonel%29), who <s>**ate**</s> are different characters, the first being an Enterprise crewmember and the second being an encountered Klingon.

Comment: **ate** was a typo, but it's too funny for me to fix

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDeC5ifgTM4

Comment: Without clicking on the link, I'm going to suspect that this is the cellular peptide cake scene.

Comment: @Praxis, nope, that would fit slightly better, but not as funny

Comment: .... with mint frosting!

Comment: Didn't Dorn also played Kirk's Klingon defense attorney in the Undiscovered Country?

Comment: @HannoverFist, that is Col. Worf.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I thought Col. Worf was from some TNG or Voyager ep I missed. I didn't remember him eating anyone in TUC.

Answer (score 23):

## Aron Eisenberg

Played ensign Nog, here standing up to General Martok while serving as a security officer on DS9:
[image]

And here playing Karden, a Kazon youth in Voyage episode "Initiations"
[image]

Comment: Didn't he also play a human in "Sanctuary"? Not a big role but I'd say it qualifies as "alien" given that his crew member character was Ferengi.

Answer (score 17):

## Denise Crosby

([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denise_Crosby)) ([Memory-Alpha Article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Denise_Crosby))

I am surprised this wasn't added to this list, and though it's not a super long answer, it appears to be valid by the constraints on the question.

> Spoilers of certain episode plot lines exist further on, abort now if you wish to avoid them!

***FEDERATION:***

**Lieutenant Natasha ("Tasha") Yar**, who was security chief (and tactical officer) on the Enterprise D before Worf was assigned as chief of security / tactical after her death in the series.  She was a big part of the *USS Enterprise-D*'s crew as chief of security and tactical officer.

[image: Denise Crosby, as Lieutenant Natasha "Tasha" Yar]

And this is a short list of aliens she played, but she played a well known nemesis of the Enterprise and the Federation...

***ALIEN:***

If you didn't know this before, Denise also played Romulan **Commander Sela**, a well known Romulan enemy.

[image: Denise Crosby, as Commander Sela]

Sela was behind the following major events, to my best recollection (this is not, however, a complete list of her appearances):

- Geordi LaForge's abduction and brainwashing (in which he tried to kill a Klingon official, during TNG 4x24, "The Mind's Eye"), and
- providing aid, supplies, military assistance, and other resources to the Duras family during the Klingon Civil War (TNG 4x26 and 5x01, "Redemption", parts 1 and 2).
- She was behind the plot to send Vulcan ships filled with Romulan troops to Vulcan, during "Unification" part 2 (TNG 5x08), in an attempt to invade Vulcan under the pretense of 'reunification' of the Vulcan and Romulan peoples.

> All images listed here are from [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com)'s page on [Denise Crosby](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Denise_Crosby), though the system here on StackExchange forced an Imgur upload.

Answer (score 14):

## Rene Auberjonois

played Odo on *DS9* and a Kantare named [Ezral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ezral) on *Enterprise*

I would also note that during seasons 4 and 5, 
Odo is human after being transformed by the link.   (This is not required by OP, but he stated he would have added the restriction except there were already so many answers.)

From "Broken Link"

> BASHIR: Physiologically, you're completely human.

Comment: I add this because it fits the letter of "encountered alien".  I'd also add Odo was human for two seasons, although that's not required by the question.

Comment: He also played Colonel West in ST VI: The Undiscovered Country.

Comment: @BrandonDybala:   Yes, but not an alien.

Comment: Not sure solid is necessarily human

Comment: @JNF, see edit.   It can't get more clear than such a plain statement by the CMO right after examining him.

Comment: Ok then. But how would Bashir know what human is? ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I was surprised not to see

### [Suzie Plakson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0686442/?ref_=tt_cl_t9#actress)

on the list.

In *The Next Generation*, she played Lt. Selar in *The Schizoid Man*
[image: Lt. Selar]
as well as K'Ehleyr (with whom Worf fathered Alexander) in *The Emissary* and *Reunion*.
[image: K'Ehleyr]

She would later play the Female Q in the *Voyager* episode *The Q and the Grey*
[image: Female Q]
as well as the Andorian Tarah in the *Enterprise* episode *Cease Fire*:
[image: Tarah]

Not as high of a count as others, but Selar and K'Ehleyr meet the requirements of the question (without the constraint added in a comment) *in a single season of the same show*.

Answer (score 12):

### Stewart Moss (TOS)

[Stewart Moss](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stewart_Moss) appeared in the TOS episode [*The Naked Time*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Naked_Time_(episode)) as **Starfleet lieutenant junior grade** [Joe Tormolen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joe_Tormolen), and later in the TOS episode [*By Any Other Name*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/By_Any_Other_Name_(episode)) as **[Kelvan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelvan) alien** [Hanar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hanar).

Moss confirmed in [an interview](http://www.startrek.com/article/interview-stewart-moss-two-time-original-series-guest-star) that he is the only **TOS** actor satisfying the OP's criteria:

> My being cast in “By Any Other Name” happened because the director of “The Naked Time,” Marc Daniels, asked for me. As it turned out **I was the only actor in The Original Series to guest star as both a crewmember and an alien**. The guest cast on “By Any Other Name” was excellent. It included Warren Stevens, a charter member of the Actor’s Studio, and two lovely ladies, Barbara Bouchet and Julie Cobb.

Comment: Funny he took a different name in that episode.

Answer (score 9):

This may or may not count since it is pre-Federation but [Vaughn Armstrong](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vaughn_Armstrong) played [Admiral Forrest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maxwell_Forrest) in the "normal" universe and [Captain Forrest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maximilian_Forrest) in the mirror universe (where he certainly was an Enterprise crew member) in ST:ENT as well as [various aliens in various series](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vaughn_Armstrong#Other_appearances) including Klingons, Cardassians, Vidiians, and Romulans:

- Korris (Klingon) in "Heart of Glory" (TNG) and "Shades of Gray" (TNG).
- Danar (Cardassian) in "Past Prologue" (DS9).
- Telek R'Mor (Romulan) in "Eye of the Needle" (VOY).
- Seskal (Cardassian) in "When It Rains..." (DS9) and "The Dogs of War" (DS9).
- Lansor (unknown species) in "Survival Instinct" (VOY).
- Unnamed Captain (Vidiian) in "Fury" (VOY).
- Unnamed Alpha (Hirogen) in "Flesh and Blood" (VOY).
- Korath (Klingon) in "Endgame" (VOY).
- Unnamed Captain (Klingon) in "Sleeping Dogs" (ENT).
- Unnamed Captain (Kreetassan) in "Vox Sola" (ENT) and "A Night in Sickbay" (ENT).

The last two are interesting because they were in the same series as his human characters.

I think James Doohan also deserves a mention. He played Scotty but he also did [voice work](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/James_Doohan#Voice_roles) for Sargon (an alien with no body in "Return to Tomorrow"), the M5 computer ("The Ultimate Computer"), The Oracle of the People ("For the World is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky"), and various aliens in the animated series.

Majel Barrett would also qualify. She played Nurse Chapel in TOS (a crew member) and Lwaxana Troi (an alien) in TNG and DS9.

Comment: Not an Enterprise, DS9, or Voyager crewmember

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Unless you count the mirror universe where Forrest was on the Enterprise.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: But she was never crew, just an occasional guest.

Comment: @muistooshort Argh, some shortcut in my brain thought this was about *Deanna*

Answer (score 7):

## Brent Spiner

Brent Spiner played the role of Lt Cdr Data in TNG as well as the role of his brother [Lore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lore) (who *could* be considered an alien). He also played [B-4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B-4) in *Star Trek: Nemesis*.

He also played [Dr. Noonian Soong](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noonian_Soong) on several episodes of TNG.  He's human, but lives off earth, so he's an alien by citizenship maybe?

For completeness, he also played [Arik Soong](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arik_Soong) on Enterprise, but that was a human on earth, so I guess that doesn't equate to an alien.

Answer (score 6):

**Majel Barrett-Roddenberry**

Majel Barrett-Roddenberry payed Nurse Christine Chapel and and a ailuroid communications officer named M'Ress in TOS and Lwaxana Troi on Star Trek: TNG and DS9.

As an aside she is also the regular voice of the onboard computers of Federation starships

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Mark Lenard played the first Romulan commander seen on screen during "Balance of Terror" in TOS; he later played Spock's father Sarek in the series and movies as well as during TNG. He also played the Commander of the Amar in Star Trek The Motion Picture

James Horan played Dr. Jo'Bril in the TNG episode [Suspicions](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708780/?ref_=ttep_ep22) (S06E22); he later played Lieutenant Barnaby in [Descent](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708701/?ref_=ttep_ep1) (S07E01)

Comment: Mark Lenard also played a Klingon in "Star Trek The Motion Picture". Of course, none of those appearances are crew members.

Answer (score 5):

Ethan Phillips
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethan_Phillips

He played Neelix and several Ferengi

Comment: And which one of these is a "Starfleet crewmember", as requested by the OP?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Neelix was a crew member (Morale Officer) and honorary Starfleet member, as were other conscripted officers such as Seven of Nine and the Maquis.

Comment: We won't hold any of these roles against him.

Answer (score 4):

## J.G. Hertzler

Well, to be honest, kind of. Depends of what you define a crew member of the main vessel for DS9. As his main character General Martok he is stationed on DS9 for quite some time. He was one of my favourite actors to spot again and again in Star Trek (and because he was missing here, I just made an account for this answer).

**Warning! Spoilers might be contained in this post!**

- General Martok (part of the combined Federation/Klingon/Romulan alliance with their main counsel on DS9)
- Martok's Changeling double
- A different Changeling Laas (billed as Garman Hertzler)
- A Worm Hole Alien (aka Prophet)
- A Vulcan Captain of a Federation ship
- A Human artist in *DS9: "Far Beyond the Stars"*
- Some Holo Suit guy
- A Hirogen fighter in Voyager
- Kolos, a Klingon in ENT
- A different Klingon in ENT

see [J.G. Hertzler in MA](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/J.G._Hertzler) for details

I'd love to also add [Jeffrey Combs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Combs), but that is stretching "main crew member" too far.

If you think Leonard Nimoy as a valid answer because of Evil Spock, you could count just about every member of DS9's main crew, as most of them have played counterparts in that universe as well (also most have played a worm hole alien in that series).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this fits the requirements but **Diana Muldaur** was Doctor Katherine Pulaski on TNG for the second season.

[image]

In the TOS episode *Is There in Truth No Beauty?,* she also played hitchhiking telepathic doctor **Miranda Jones** that the Enterprise picked up. She was escorting the Medusan Ambassador Kollos. Technically she was human though she never visited earth - she was "alien" to the crew.

[image]

She was also crew member **Ann Mulhall** in the TOS episode *Return to Tomorrow* where she was "possessed" by an alien entity who used her body. Again, this also may not fit exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes !

This question immediately made me think about Quark (played by Armin Shimerman) ! The ferengi on DS9. He was first encountered in TNG and played another ferengi called Letek (Episode "The Last Outpost") !

- Letek

  [image: Letek]
- Quark
  [image: Quark]
- Armin Shimerman
  [image: Armin Shimerman]

(PS. Maybe this is not exactly a crewmember but he was a member of the main cast and worth mentioning in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

## Leonard Nimoy

Leonard Nimoy played [First Officer Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock) during the original series and several films. In the TOS episode ["Mirror, Mirror"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_(episode)), he played [Goateed Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock_(mirror)), first officer of the ISS Enterprise of the [Terran Empire](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Terran_Empire).

[image: Goateed Spock]