# Which character in Star Trek has been played by the most actors?

Tags: star-trek, actors, star-trek-reboot

Some recurring characters have been played by different actors in different films or episodes. Many main cast members have been portrayed by different actors due to flashbacks, and *[(mumble) insert (mumble) technobabble (mumble)]* shenanigans. Of course the 2009 reboot opens up a universe of characters being played by a new generation of actors.

## Which Star Trek character was portrayed by the most different actors?

**Clarifications:**

- The character must be substantially the same: alternate timelines count at the same character, but for example, [Shinzon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shinzon) is not Picard.
- Janeway played by a lizard counts, just because it won't affect the answer and it makes me chuckle.
- "possessions" (Spock in McCoy in *Star Trek III* and everyone in "Facets") do not count. This is DeForest Kelley playing Dr. McCoy containing some aspect of Spock, not DeForst Kelley playing Spock.  The litmus test is, Would the IMDB or the credits reasonably credit  Kelley as Spock? (This is going to be a little debatable, but it doesn't appear it will affect the accepted answer.)

Related:  [Which actor has portrayed the most distinct roles in the Star Trek universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31810/which-actor-has-portrayed-the-most-distinct-roles-in-the-star-trek-universe)

Comment: Do voiceovers and other voicework count as portrayal?

Comment: I vote red shirt #2

Comment: @matts:   I suppose yes.

Comment: Do video game avatar appearances count?

Comment: @Xantec:   That's non-canon, whatever that means in Star Trek.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I missed your `in different films or episodes` requirement anyway, so they wouldn't count.

Comment: I think [Majel Barrett](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000854/) played the most distinct roles she voiced most of the computers, Number One (in the pilot) Nurse (later Commander) Chapel and Lwaxana Troi.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I'm inclined to think "Computer Voice" counts as one character, at least within the same era.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero, sure there are more of Red Shirt #1

Comment: @ThePopMachine Perhaps, but of which ship? DS9, Enterprise, Voyager? Presumably they're all different "computers".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, do people imagine there are 100 millions Siris?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Does Siri have genuine people personality? Because I think the ships of ST *might*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you're answering [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31810/which-actor-has-portrayed-the-most-distinct-roles-in-the-star-trek-universe) anyhow,  not this one here.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I know I'm answering the inverse of this question, which is why I made it a comment. :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, go put answer at the linked question.   It's a good potential answer.

Comment: If you want to count voicework as portrayal, you may want to exclude foreign dubbings, where each character has at least one additional voice actor per language.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, no,  no foreign dubbings.  That's not generally what we count in canon,  and it would drive the question in a different,  and I think uninteresting Dixon.   (Although one could ask a separate question)

Comment: Interesting that IMDB credits both actors for both roles in "Face/Off" (imitation) and "18 Again!" (possession), but not in "Mission Impossible II" (imitation) or either version of "Freaky Friday" (possession). So I suspect the IMDB litmus test might boil down to what your agent can get you.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch - your use of the term "Genuine People Personalities" violates the copyright of the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation. This is something which the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation takes seriously, and the consequences of such a violation can be quite serious. However, seeing as how your home planet has already been scheduled for demolition to make way for a hyperspace bypass we'll let it go - but we *will* contact our wholly-owned subsidiary, Vogon Constructors, Inc, and make certain that the hyperspace project in your neighborhood is prioritized. Thank you, and have a nice day! :-)

Comment: The guy who played Shinzon also portrayed Picard in an old picture. Does that count?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Majel Barrett also voiced M'ress in the Animated Series.

Comment: I don't think I could justify this as an answer, but technically every actor who's ever played a Borg Drone was a *part* of the same character, since the collective functions as a single organism.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish:  Tricky.   But, no.

Comment: I suppose Odo runs afoul of the IMDB test, but it would be interesting to see a count of all the actors (in addition to René Auberjonois) that played a transformed Odo, however briefly.

Comment: @chepner:   I don't think he ever really impersonated anyone.   He wasn't that proficient (the other changelings were).   But you could ask how many objects played Odo...

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ah, it's been long time since I watched DS9.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Mr. Spock (12, up to 15)

**Definite:**

1. Leonard Nimoy, most famously
2. Zachary Quinto in the reboot continuity
3. [Jacob Kogan](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2275042/) played the young Spock in *Star Trek (2009)*
4. Spock appears as a baby in *Star Trek V*, although the name of the "actor" is unknown, so far as I know
5. [Carl Steven](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0828186/?ref_=tt_cl_t13) played nine-year-old Spock in *Star Trek III*
6. [Vadia Potenza](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0693071/?ref_=tt_cl_t14) played 13-year-old Spock in *Star Trek III*
7. [Stephen Manley](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0542603/?ref_=tt_cl_t15) played 17-year-old Spock in *Star Trek III*
8. [Joe W. Davis](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0202926/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t16) played 25-year-old Spock in *Star Trek III*
9. [Frank Welker](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0919798/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t39) provided Spock's screams in *Star Trek III*
10. [Billy Simpson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0800916#actor-tt0069637) voiced yet another young version of Spock in the *Star Trek: The Animated Series* episode "[Yesteryear](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Yesteryear_(episode))"
11. [Ethan Peck](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ethan_Peck) portrays Spock in *Star Trek: Discovery* and *Star Trek: Strange New Worlds*
12. [Liam Hughes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Liam_Hughes) portrays young Spock in childhood flashbacks in *Star Trek: Discovery*

**Debatable:**

13. DeForest Kelley played something Spock-like<sup>1</sup> in scenes in *Star Trek III* where McCoy was taken over by Spock's *katra*
14. [Carey Scott](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0778931/) recorded some scenes as a younger Spock for *Star Trek V*, but they were cut from the finished film
15. Yet another baby Spock appears in a [deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaAusqTaqcA) filmed for *Star Trek (2009)*, [apparently](https://twitter.com/jakeyvaughn/status/572111992510533632) played by child actress [Jenna Vaughn](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm6618259#actress-tt0796366); the scene is available on the DVD release

---

<sup>1</sup> There's at least one scene in the movie where Spock's *katra* (soul) completely takes over McCoy's body:

> **McCoy:** (in Spock's voice) Jim, ...Help me. ...You left me on Genesis. ...Why did you do that? ...Help me.
>
> **Kirk:** Bones, ...what the hell are you doing? Have you lost your mind!
>
> **McCoy:** Help me, Jim. ...Take me home.
>
> **Kirk:**  Bones, we are. We are home.
>
> **McCoy:** Then perhaps it's not too late. ...Climb the steps, Jim. ...Climb the steps of Mount Seleya.
>
> **Kirk:** Mount Seleya? Bones, Mount Seleya is on Vulcan! We're home, ...on Earth!
>
> **McCoy:** (in Spock's voice) Remember!
>
> <sup>*Star Trek III: The Search For Spock* (1984)</sup>

However McCoy is still in there somewhere; it's unclear to what extent he and Spock are mingling inside McCoy's body.

Comment: @Praxis:  Probably yes, but can people offer the pro and con arguments for DeForest Kelley?

Comment: @JasonBaker : Did this "young Spock" appear on screen in *Star Trek V*, or is that footage that wasn't used? (Carey Scott would have been 23 when the film came out.)  Also, there was a baby Spock in that film, seen during a vision induced by Sybok. That would count as an additional actor (the baby).

Comment: @Praxis I think you might be right; Cary Scott's scene may have been cut. I'll update in a moment

Comment: @ThePopMachine It depends on how you feel about possession; but if you consider, for example, Nana Visitor as having played Lela Dax (ignoring the Trill joining issue), I see no reason not to include it

Comment: If we allow possessions, [I think we have to allow symbiots](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105833/1441).

Comment: I think McCoy as Spock is definitely in the "debatable" category. It's still DeForest Kelley playing *McCoy*, who just happens to be carrying around Spock's essence.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was thinking specifically of a scene early in *Star Trek III* where Kirk goes into Bones' room and "Bones" implores Kirk to take him "home", to a mountain on Vulcan. In that scene at least (and possibly others; it's been a while since I saw the whole movie), I don't think it's reasonable to say that Kelley is playing McCoy

Comment: Right, but even in universe, that's McCoy's body, not Spock's. Even if you consider the mind to be the character, there is still unarguably at least a portion of McCoy involved. I think whether one character's miind inhabiting a completely different character's body, especially without actually ousting the other character's mind, counts here is debatable. It's certainly not clear from the question whether the OP intends for it to count.

Comment: @jpmc26 and JasonBaker:   I don't think I accept possessions.   It doesn't actually change the final answer, but I'm feeling swayed that Kelley isn't playing Spock.   Kelley is playing McCoy, who is imbued with Spock's essence.  Think about it think way:   IMDB or the credits are not going to credit Kelley with playing Spock.   I suggest moving it to the 'debatable' category.

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, I'm still of the opinion that it should count, but you've convinced me that it's at least debatable; moved back down

Comment: @ThePopMachine See above

Comment: Regardless the Kelley/McCoy/Spock thing, excellent answer. (I think I have to reluctantly agree with jpmc26, Kelley was playing McCoy who was possessed. IIRC (long time for me too), they even used Nimoy's voice for one line, seeming to come from McCoy's body, which really gave Kirk a start.) Doesn't matter, great answer.

Comment: Add in fan films................

Comment: Spock is also portrayed in various video games such as the upcoming [Resurgence](https://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/ent/spock-leonard-nimoy-star-trek-resurgence.html), and it looks like the actor's name is [Piotr Michael](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3086712/)

Answer (score 26):

### Dax (14 actors, 1 puppet)

After preliminary research the Trill Dax seems to have the most actors that played it.

**Lela Dax**

[image]

**Tobin Dax**

[image]

**Emony Dax**

[image]

**Audrid Dax**

[image]

**Torias Dax**

[image]

**Joran Dax** played by multiple people, Jeff Magnus McBride,
Leigh J. McCloskey,
Avery Brooks (in Benjamin Sisko's body)

[image]

**Curzon Dax** also played by multiple, Frank Owen Smith (DS9: "Emissary");
Rene Auberjonois (DS9: "Facets")

[image]

**Jadzia Dax**

[image]

**Ezri Dax**

[image]

**Yedrin Dax** Alternate timeline

[image]

**Verad Dax**

[image]

**Dax**

[image]

15 in total (14 actors and one puppet) played a part of Dax's life.

Comment: But Dax is Trill symbiont. It just changes host body, so every time it is different person.

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic same entity, 14 different versions

Comment: I'd argue that the *symbiont* was only played by one character

Comment: @JasonBaker Dax still carries the memories from one host to the next, each host is personally responsible for its actions but the symbiotic entity Dax is still its own being.

Comment: @ Himarm No it is same 50% of entity. Each of those 14 persons have completely different lifes in completely different times. Dax only holds memories from host's, there are not same persons every time. Not like above mentioned Spock, it is always Spock ,every time same person who did same things and was friend with James T. Kirk, but played by different actors

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic the entity DAX has merged X many times, but DAX is still the same symbiot, therefore even though hes in Different hosts, its still the 100% the same Dax, + a new body. so the character Dax has 14 iterations, while the combined character of jazdia dax only has 1.

Comment: @ Himarm I agree it is every time same symbiot. Every time same thing, it was never played by many character because it is some CGI crafted slug-like creature . It always looked the same, it never changed and as Richard above said we can say it was only played by one "character"

Comment: Sorry everyone, it's a plot point that after every merging, the Trill is a new person.   This is not the same character.

Comment: @ThePopMachine its a plot point that the trill is "legally" considered a new person, after clever court room proceedings.  Despite the fact that the "new" person has every memory the last one had.

Comment: @Himarm:  "Dax":  PEERS: ...it's a joining. It's a total sharing, a blending, of both host and symbiont. Neither is suppressed by the other. 
SISKO: So with each new host there does come in fact, a new personality, a new combined person. A different person.

Comment: ... to your precise point:   Having the memories of =/= is the same person

Comment: Don't forget Dax! The question says Janeway as a lizard qualifies, so Dax as a puppet must also qualify.

Answer (score 9):

### Jean-Luc Picard = 5

Jean-Luc Picard was portrayed in the main TV series by three separate actors:

- Patrick Stewart (in every episode of TNG)
- David Birkin (in TNG: Rascals)
- Marcus Nash (TNG: Tapestry)

He was also pictured as a [bald cadet](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/8/82/Jean-LucPicardCadet.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/180?cb=20100823195916&path-prefix=en) by Tom Hardy in *Nemesis*.

And in Season 2 of *Picard*, a 12 year-old Jean-Luc was played by [Dylan Von Halle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dylan_Von_Halle).

[image: Picard portrayed by 5 actors]

Comment: Yup that's definitely [Tom Hardy](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/f/f0/Shinzon.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20101021183055&path-prefix=en)

Comment: This was actually a mistake too, because Picard wasn't bald in Star Fleet Academy.

Comment: @JohnBell Fashion in hair can change quickly. Depilation is a thing. :)

Comment: @Praxis - The perils of posting from a phone.

Comment: @Richard : 'Tis the Bane of an answerer's existence.

Comment: @JohnBell He must have lost a bet.

Comment: When Picard lost his hair, he had all his old pictures Photoshopped.

Comment: Picard was also played by David Tristan Birkin in the TNG episode "Rascals" (as 12-year-old Picard).

Comment: @CharlesBurge - I'm just gonna sit here and wait for you to scroll up. Take your time...

Comment: Hah... so sorry... somehow I missed that.

Comment: @CharlesBurge - And there we go :-)

Comment: Why do I keep feeling like James McAvoy belongs on this list?

Answer (score 5):

Although this certainly isn’t numerically the highest, on *Deep Space Nine* Gul Dukat’s daughter [Tora Ziyal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tora_Ziyal) was played by three different actresses in a little over two years, without any flashbacks or sci-fi shenanigans.

In season 4, Cyia Batten portrayed her in [Indiscretion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Indiscretion_(episode)) and [Return to Grace](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace_(episode)), with Tracy Middendorf taking over in [For The Cause](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/For_the_Cause_(episode)).

Melanie Smith then played her in six episodes split evenly across seasons 5 and 6, finishing with

> her death, in

[Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode)).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't come close to [Spock](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105834/57529), but a worthwhile mention is [Naomi Wildman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Naomi_Wildman) who was played by four different actresses.

1. Scarlett Pomers (in 16 episodes of Voyager)
2. Emily Leibovitch (a baby, VOY Deadlock and Basics, Part II)
3. Brooke Stephens (a younger Naomi, VOY Mortal Coil)
4. Vanessa Branch (a future adult Naomi, VOY Shattered)

Worf's son [Alexander Rozhenko](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alexander_Rozhenko) was also played by four different actors: Brian Bonsall, Marc Worden, James Sloyan, and Jon Steuer.

Apparently [Miral Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Miral_Paris) was also portrayed by four different actresses, although one of those was a hologram of an "unknown actress" and two are twin babies (one of them being male, interestingly enough).

[Tom Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tom_Paris) was portrayed by 4 actors as well if you're including the lizard — though I suppose the Steth thing might qualify as a "posession". Plus he was also portrayed in animated form in Lower Decks, though he was still voiced by Robert Duncan McNeill.