# Who is this Voyager character?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, character-identification

Re- watching Voyager last night I came across this guy

[image]

His voice seems SOOO familiar and I could swear that I have heard/seen him in many other Sci-fi shows (Star Trek shows included). Am I just imagining stuff?

Comment: :) So are you looking for the actor, the character, both?

Comment: While the question is already answered, what did you attempt to figure it out on your own? You probably knew the episode title or even the character name, from whose memory alpha entry you could directly have found http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Combs...

Comment: I'd recognize Weyoun's insipid smile anywhere...

Comment: The voice and actor was so cemented as Weyoun/Brunt in my mind, that when I saw that Voyager episode at first I sincerely thought that they were somehow bringing the Dominion War into the Delta quadrant, and disguising Weyoun for some reason. It really threw me for a loop that I heard "Weyoun" there but it wasn't really him. (Even though at the time I think I knew that Combs had done several other characters.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### [Jeffrey Combs](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001062/) as [Penk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Penk)

He's been in [a lot](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Combs) of Star Trek episodes:

> Combs has since earned himself quite a number of appearances on Star Trek, guest starring in thirty-one episodes of Deep Space Nine, **one episode of Star Trek: Voyager**, and eleven episodes of Star Trek: Enterprise.".

He's even referred to as *[Star Trek's Mr. Everywhere](http://www.startrek.com/article/star-trekundefineds-mr-everywhere-undefined-a-jeffrey-combs-interview-part-1)* over on [StarTrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/).

I know him best as **Milton Dammers** from [The Frighteners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116365/?ref_=nm_knf_t2):

Comment: “He's been in a lot of Star Trek episodes” — playing [a lot of different characters](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31827/440).

Comment: He'll always be [Herbert West](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089885/) to me.